# Comparison of the change of variable theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I would like to compare the change of variable theorem for 1 variable and more. What are the differences, in which case we need stronger assumptions? How do they differ? What is the best way to **write** the theorems for comparison?

Multivariable:

Let $\varphi : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ (where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ and $k\leq n)$ be injective and differentiable with continuous partial derivatives. Then for every $f: \varphi(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n:$

$$\int_{\varphi(\Omega)} f(y) dy=\int_\Omega f(\varphi(x))|J\varphi(x)| dx,  $$

One variable:

If $\varphi:[a,b] \rightarrow I \subset \mathbb{R}$ has continuos derivative. Let $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$ Then: 
$$\int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(b)} f(y) dy=\int_{a}^{b} f(\varphi(x))\varphi'(x) dx$$

I think that the $1-1$ function in multivariable is an important difference, but I don't know why I need this assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that the $1$-dimensional integral is **oriented**. This manifests itself in two ways:

1. We write $\phi'(t)$ instead of $|\phi'(t)|$.
2. By transforming the boundaries of the integral, the orientation is also taken into account. For example if $\phi$ is (strictly) decreasing, then $\phi(a) > \phi(b)$ and hence

$$
\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)} f(s) \, ds = -\int_{\phi(b)}^{\phi(a)} f(s) \, ds =-\int_{(\phi(b),\phi(a))} f(s)\, d\lambda(s).
$$

This is the reason, why $\phi$ does not necessarily have to be injective for the $1$-dimensional case. If $\phi$ is not injective, the sign of the derivative will vary, so that the "double parts" cancel each other out in the sum.

For the multidimensional case, no cancellation can happen, because we take the absolute value of the determinant of the jacobian.

Everything said above is not really rigorous, but I hope it clarifies the difference slightly.

Comment: Could you tell me if I wrote the theorems right? Are the domains and ranges of the functions correct?

Comment: Yes, they are right. Of course, you have to put some measurabiliy/integrability assumption on $f$. For the first theorem (multivariable case), if $f$ is measurable, then either side of the equality exists iff the other side does (at least if $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism, see next). Also, the usual (easy) version of the multivariable case is that of a **diffeomorphism** $\phi : \Omega \to \phi(\Omega)$, which in particular implies $n=k$. If you allow $k\leq n$, then the "$dy$" needs to be the surface measure ($k$-dimensional Hausdorff measure) in the expression $\int_{\phi(\Omega)} f(y) \, dy$.